# How to ensure make eclipse-project grabs all dependencies

Tags: ros, manifest.xml, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been struggling with this a couple of times before and always found work-arounds to overcome, but there must be a better way.

I develop my ROS-related code with Eclipse. So I always use make eclipse-project to create and update .project file as described on the [IDEs ROS Wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs) page. The problem is, make eclipse-project doesn't usually automatically grab package dependencies between packages I wrote.

I never have any problems with dependencies between packages installed from binary packages. But the weird thing is I never have any problems with eg. crawling trough packages I wrote with **`roscd`** or using other ros CLI commands to explore my package tree neither. So **`ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`** is set correctly. I also edited **`manifest.xml`** to add

```
<depend package="my_package"/>
```

so that should be right as well. But then I check **`Project properties -> C/C++ Include Paths and Preprocessor Symbols`** and the required package includes are missing.

What are the common pitfalls I can be dealing with?

**EDIT:** OK I think a probable cause of my problems is me not knowing anything about the correct usage of the  tag in the manifest.xml file. Is [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest/XML#export) the only documentation to it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10793/how-to-ensure-make-eclipse-project-grabs-all-dependencies/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-08-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, it's definitely it, after adding compiler and linker flags in manifest.xml all works fine. It also seems the only documentation to it is the one stated in the question, so a certain knowledge of makefile syntax is assumed. I, for instance, added this:

```
<export>
    <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/src" lflags="-L${prefix}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -lMyLib"/>
</export>
```

This will cause my header files from **`src`** to be exported (I'm not following the convention to place header files in an **`include`** directory, so maybe you'll have to replace src with include), a library directory added to linker's knowledge and a library libMyLib.so (or .o) placed in one of the above declared directories to be linked.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2